# DataSet not saving the data

Tags: c#

This is the first time I am using DataSet. Below is my code

```
var transactionSet = new ModelExecutionContext()
        {
            TransactionSet = new DataSet()
            {
                Tables = { new DataTable()
                {
                    TableName = "transaction_history"
                }
                }
            }
        };

        transactionSet.TransactionSet.Tables["transaction_history"].Columns.Add().ColumnName = "retailer_reference_id";
        var retailerReferenceIdRow = transactionSet.TransactionSet.Tables["transaction_history"].NewRow();
        retailerReferenceIdRow["retailer_reference_id"] = 8;

        transactionSet.TransactionSet.AcceptChanges();
```

I am unit testing a method in a class which has the datasets. I am trying to mock those datasets. I thought `transactionSet.TransactionSet.AcceptChanges();` will save the changes into the `DataSet`, but in the execution, I am getting `context?.TransactionSet?.Tables["transaction_history"]?.Rows.Count` = **0**

Is anything incorrect with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you created object of row you need to add row to table.

```
transactionSet.TransactionSet.Tables["transaction_history"].Rows.Add(retailerReferenceIdRow);
```